# syntaxerror: "unexpected character after line continuation character in python" math

Tags: python, math, syntax, continuation

I am having problems with this Python program I am creating to do maths, working out and so solutions but I'm getting the syntaxerror: "unexpected character after line continuation character in python"

this is my code

```
print("Length between sides: "+str((length*length)*2.6)+" \ 1.5 = "+str(((length*length)*2.6)\1.5)+" Units")
```

My problem is with **\1.5** I have tried **\1.5** but it doesn't work

Using python 2.7.2

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The division operator is `/`, not `\`

Comment: I switched to using *0.666666667 then I saw this...I might just stick to what I have written now.

Answer (score 19):

The backslash `\` is the line continuation character the error message is talking about, and after it, only newline characters/whitespace are allowed (before the next non-whitespace continues the "interrupted" line.

```
print "This is a very long string that doesn't fit" + \
      "on a single line"
```

Outside of a string, a backslash can only appear in this way. For division, you want a slash: `/`.

If you want to write a verbatim backslash in a string, escape it by doubling it: `"\\"`

In your code, you're using it twice:

```
 print("Length between sides: " + str((length*length)*2.6) +
       " \ 1.5 = " +                   # inside a string; treated as literal
       str(((length*length)*2.6)\1.5)+ # outside a string, treated as line cont
                                       # character, but no newline follows -> Fail
       " Units")
```

Answer (score 9):

You must press enter after continuation character

Note: Space after continuation character leads to error

```
cost = {"apples": [3.5, 2.4, 2.3], "bananas": [1.2, 1.8]}

0.9 * average(cost["apples"]) + \ """enter here"""
0.1 * average(cost["bananas"])
```

Comment: Wow - this little nugget of information - spent a lot of time trying to figure out why the code wasn't working; didn't know about "pressing enter immediately after the line continuation character" thanks a ton!

Answer (score 2):

The division operator is `/` rather than `\`.

Also, the backslash has a special meaning inside a Python string. Either escape it with another backslash:

```
"\\ 1.5 = "`
```

or use a raw string

```
r" \ 1.5 = "
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, what do you try to do? If you want to use division, use "/" not "\".
If it is something else, explain it in a bit more detail, please.

Answer (score 0):

As the others already mentioned: the division operator is **/** rather than ****.
If you wanna print the **** character within a string you have to escape it:

```
print("foo \\")
# will print: foo \
```

I think to print the string you wanted I think you gonna need this code:

```
print("Length between sides: " + str((length*length)*2.6) + " \\ 1.5 = " + str(((length*length)*2.6)/1.5) + " Units")
```

And this one is a more readable version of the above (using the format method):

```
message = "Length between sides: {0} \\ 1.5 = {1} Units"
val1 = (length * length) * 2.6
val2 = ((length * length) * 2.6) / 1.5
print(message.format(val1, val2))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not related to the question; just for future purpose. In my case, I got this error message when using regex. Here is my code and the correction

```
text = "Hey I'm Kelly, how're you and how's it going?"
import re
```

When I got error:

```
x=re.search(r'('\w+)|(\w+'\w+)', text)
```

The correct code:

```
x=re.search(r"('\w+)|(\w+'\w+)", text)
```

I'm meant to use double quotes after the r instead of single quotes.