# Python syntaxerror: unexpected character after line continuation character

Tags: python, newline, syntax-error

I'm just starting python so am most likely just doing something stupid. I'm reading data off of a table and need to put them into columns in a txt file. I cannot convince my code to create a new line.

Here is my code-

```
file = open("test_m.rdb")
table = open('table.txt', 'w+')

trash = file.readline()

trash = file.readline()

data = file.readline()
i = data.split()
flux = i[2]
observed = i[4]
table.write(flux + " " + observed,)

while 1:
    line = file.readline()
    i = line.split()
    try:
        flux = i[2]
        observed = i[4]
    except IndexError:
        break
    table.write(\nflux + " " + observed)
table.close()
```

And the error reads-

```
File "PlotRdbFile.py", line 24
    table.write(\nflux + " " + observed)
                                   ^
SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character
```

Thank you in advance for finding my mistake.

Comment: possible duplicate of [syntaxerror: "unexpected character after line continuation character in python" math](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7791913/syntaxerror-unexpected-character-after-line-continuation-character-in-python)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
table.write(\nflux + " " + observed)
```

should be

```
table.write("\n" + flux + " " + observed)
```

or alternatively

```
table.write("\n{} {}".format(flux, observed))
```

More information about [format()](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) if you are curious.

Comment: Thank you! 
I have a followup question. I tried table.write("\n" + flux + " " + observed) before I posted this question. I thought it wasn't working properly because when I open up the txt file with notepad, it puts all the data on one line. When I tried it a second time after you answered my question, I opened it with Word and it is formatted correctly but it still isn't formatted correctly when I open the file in Notepad. Do you know why that is?

Comment: And thank you for the format() link. It's going to be very helpful.

Comment: @Elerrina different word processor/editors will display data sometimes differently unfortunately (mostly a matter how they handle newlines). I use `emacs`, probably not the most user-friendly editor for my programming, not sure what I can recommend to you. I've heard good things about notepad++ http://www.notepad-plus-plus.org/ maybe you can check it out.