# syntax error unexpected character after line continuation character python

Tags: python, character, syntax-error

my code is,

```
import MySQLdb
import collections
from pymongo import Connection

from config.MySQLdb import *
from config.MongoDB import *
from config.SyncTables import *

db = MySQLdb.connect(DB_HOST,DB_USR,DB_PWD,DB_NAME)
cursor = db.cursor()
query = "SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE userid = 1"
cursor.execute(query)
row = cursor.fetchall()

mconn = Connection(MONGODB_HOST,MONGODB_PORT)
mdb = mconn[MONGODB_DBNAME]
#col = mdb[trngl_advertiser_agegroup]

db.trngl_advertiser_agegroup .insert({'id': row[0],'userid':row[1], 'ageid':row[2],       'age_value':row[3], \                                             'created':row[4],  'modified':row[5]})
print "after update"
```

but I'm getting this error,

```
triongle@triongle.com [~/download/DataInsertionScript]# python IngestDataToMongo.py

  File "IngestDataToMongo.py", line 21
    db.table_name.insert({'id': row[0],'userid':row[1], 'ageid':row[2],  'age_value':row[3],\                                                       'created':row[4], 'modified':row[5]})
                                                                                                                                                                                               ^

SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character
```

But I don't see any unexpected character after . So please tell me, why I'm getting this error

The error image is,
[image]

Comment: No need for the backslash :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [syntaxerror: "unexpected character after line continuation character in python" math](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7791913/syntaxerror-unexpected-character-after-line-continuation-character-in-python)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code is all on one line, but you are using a line continuation escape character (`\`). Remove that character:

```
db.trngl_advertiser_agegroup .insert({'id': row[0],'userid':row[1], 'ageid':row[2], 'age_value':row[3], 'created':row[4],  'modified':row[5]})
```

You do not need to use such a line continuation trick *at all* when you break the line inside parenthesis or brackets, you can safely put the statement on multiple lines without it:

```
db.trngl_advertiser_agegroup .insert({
    'id': row[0],
    'userid':row[1], 
    'ageid':row[2], 
    'age_value':row[3],
    'created':row[4],
    'modified':row[5]
})
```

Comment: thanks, it worked after removing that character. But I'm really frustrated with python and mongodb connection. Yesterday, it was giving me error when I didn't use \, and today my some code is on next line, and no need to use \. Now I'm thinking why it is showing me my code split-ed in 2 lines. I'm seeing code using cPanelX in browser

Comment: Your line was wrapped by the terminal or editor, there isn't an actual newline there, just a *hell* of a lot of extra whitespace that is redundant.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need line continuation characters inside [], {}, or (). Feel free to put the arguments in multiple lines if you want without **\**