# Python unexpected character after line continuation character

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am very new to Python. I am constructing a string that is nothing but a path to the network location as follows. But it outputs the error: "Python unexpected character after line continuation character". Please help. I saw this post but I am not sure if it applies to my scenario:

[syntaxerror: "unexpected character after line continuation character in python" math](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7791913/syntaxerror-unexpected-character-after-line-continuation-character-in-python)

```
s_path_publish_folder = r"\\" + s_host + "\" + s_publish_folder "\" + s_release_name
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of your `\` backslashes *escapes* the `"` double quote following it. The rest of the string then *ends* just before the next `\` backslash, and that second backslash is seen as a line-continuation character. Because there's another `"` right after that you get your error:

```
s_path_publish_folder = r"\\" + s_host + "\" + s_publish_folder "\" + s_release_name
#                                         ^^ not end of string   ||
#                                        ^--- actual string  ---^||
#                                              line continuation /|
#                                                 extra character /
```

You need to *double* those backslashes:

```
s_path_publish_folder = r"\\" + s_host + "\\" + s_publish_folder "\\" + s_release_name
```

Better yet, use the `os.path` module here; for example, you could use `os.path.join()`:

```
s_path_publish_folder = r"\\" + os.path.join(s_host, s_publish_folder, s_release_name)
```

or you could use string templating:

```
s_path_publish_folder = r"\\{}\{}\{}".format(s_host, s_publish_folder, s_release_name)
```